# mudar exibição de um foreach de acordo com os dados que ele recebe

Tags: php

Nâo Sei exatamente como fazer essa pergunta, estou desenvolvendo um sistema de pizzaria, onde possui um carrinho de compras bem simples que pega o id da pizza e exibe no carrinho quando o cliente seleciona, porem preciso enviar pizza de dois sabores para esse carrinho de compras e não sei como fazer sou iniciante alguém poderia me ajudar, vou tentar esclarecer da melhor forma que eu conseguir.

eu possuo um cardápio que tem itens cadastrados no banco de dados, no cardápio mostra pizzas de um sabor como por exemplo: mussarela, até ai tudo bem

no cardápio existe um menu de pizzas dois sabores onde o cliente seleciona dois sabores e envia duas IDs via ajax para o carrinho porem o carrinho so pega uma id

segue o codigo que pega as ids

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['carrinho'])) {
    $_SESSION['carrinho'] = array();
} //adiciona produto
if (isset($_GET['acao'])) {
    //ADICIONAR CARRINHO
    if ($_GET['acao'] == 'add') {
        $id = intval($_GET['id']);
        if (!isset($_SESSION['carrinho'][$id])) {
            $_SESSION['carrinho'][$id] = 1;
        } else {
            $_SESSION['carrinho'][$id]+= 1;
        }
    }

    //REMOVER CARRINHO
    if ($_GET['acao'] == 'del') {
        $id = intval($_GET['id']);
        if (isset($_SESSION['carrinho'][$id])) {
            unset($_SESSION['carrinho'][$id]);
        }
    } //ALTERAR QUANTIDADE
    if ($_GET['acao'] == 'up') {
        if (is_array($_POST['prod'])) {
            foreach ($_POST['prod'] as $id => $qtd) {
                $id = intval($id);
                $qtd = intval($qtd);
                if (!empty($qtd) || $qtd <> 0) {
                    $_SESSION['carrinho'][$id] = $qtd;
                } else {
                    unset($_SESSION['carrinho'][$id]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

e o código do foreach
que faz a iteração do array e exibe os produtos

```
                   <?php
    $total = 0;
    foreach ($_SESSION['carrinho'] as $id => $qtd) {
        $sql = "SELECT *  FROM cadprod WHERE id_prod= '$id'";
        $qrs = mysqli_query($conn1, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn1));
        $lns = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qrs);
        $nome = $lns['nome_prod'];
        $preco = number_format($lns['preco_prod'], 2, ',', '.');
        $valor = $lns['preco_prod'];
        $sub = number_format($lns['preco_prod'] * $qtd, 2, ',', '.');
        $total+= $lns['preco_prod'] * $qtd;
                        echo '<tr>
                        <td data-th="Produto">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <h4 class="nomargin text-uppercase text-center">' . $nome . '</h4>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="text-center" data-th="Quantidade"><input  class="form-control text-center" type="number" size="3" name="prod[' . $id . ']" value="' . $qtd . '" /></td>
                            <td data-th="valor"  class="text-center">R$ ' . $preco . '</td>
                            <td data-th="Subtotal" class="text-center">R$ ' . $sub . '</td>
                            <td  data-th=" ">
                                <a  href="carrinho.php?link=' . $bdv . '&acao=del&id=' . $id . '" class="pegaHref btn btn-danger btn-md"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>                      
                            </td>
                        </tr>';
    }

     $subtotal = number_format($total, 2, '.', ',');

$frete = str_replace(",",".", $frete);
$frete =  floatval($frete);   
$valortotal = $frete + $total;
$valortotal = floatval($valortotal);




}
    ?>
```

eu estou tentando fazer com que na hora que o usuário selecionar dois sabores mostre os dois sabores da pizza no carrinho com o valor da mais cara.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caro segue uma sugestão de solução, espero que compreenda, qualquer duvida torno a responder.

Primeiro se deve confirmar que os dois valores estão sendo enviados, eu recomendo que se utilize virgula para concatenalos

```
//concatena os ids como a baixo (ou dentro de um laço de repetição pra ser mais inteligente)
ids = opcao1 + "," + opcao2; //exemplo simples
$.ajax({
 url:"..",
 data:{ids:ids}
})
```

no servidor a mudança mais significativa vai ser

```
//$_SESSION['carrinho'][$id] = 1;
 $_SESSION['carrinho'][] = [$ids,1];



//para que em algum momento seja manipulado o array de sabores de um pedido
foreach( $_SESSION['carrinho'] as $unidade){

$pizza['sabores'] = $unidade[0].split(","); //retorna array
$pizza['quantidade'] = $unidade[1];
//ok para um ou vários ids de sabor

}
```

**isso aumenta um pouco a complexidade do código mas o esforço vai ser sem duvida recompensado**

Comment: obrigado pela resposta